# Put list of datetime objects spanning multiple days into 2-hourly bins

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of datetime objects, with the date range spanning multiple years.

I would like to divide these dates into 2 hourly bins. So for the 0 hr bin, all of the datetimes from 23:00 - 1:00 would go in this bin (+/- 1 hr).

In the end I would like a list of the index of each datetime that falls within a bin. So if my datetime list was something like

```
   datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 3, 20, 29, 54, 268074),
   datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 4, 11, 28, 34, 59937),
   datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 4, 19, 40, 39, 718856),
   datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 18, 12, 17, 57, 417245),
   datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 19, 1, 37, 57, 465573)
```

I want a result of a list of lists like:

```
[[],
 [4],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [1,3],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [0,2],
 []]
```

Where result[0] give me a list of indexes that correspond to datetimes closest to the 0:00, result[0] gives a list closest to 2:00, etc.

My first thought was to use the datetime.time object to create a list of hours, and then subtract a datetime from my list and find the minimum.

```
import datetime 
hrs = array([datetime.time(t) for t in arange(0,24,2)])
closetHr = min(hrs - times[0].time())
```

But this gives me the error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: What other imports are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the expected output for the sample input, avoiding the time subtraction:

```
bins = [[] for t in arange(0,24,2)]
for i,t in enumerate(times):
    ix = (t.hour+1)%24     # "normalize" the hour
    bins[ix/2].append( i ) # convert to a bin index
```

Not clear if this does what you want when the value is on an odd-hour boundary (i.e. 1:00), but then you didn't specify.

Comment: Perfect. All of my times go down to the millisecond and therefore never fall exactly on the boundary in my dataset, so its not an issue here.

Comment: How would I modify this to divide into 3-houry bins, with +/- 1.5 hour on the each side of the hour? So the first bin would be 22:30 - 1:30 (0:00 +/1 1.5 hours), second would be 1:30 - 4:30, etc.

Comment: @user3826115: That should be its own question, but you'd need to take `t.minute` into account.